# How to check If the user provides duplicate keys in an array of key-value pair objects

Tags: javascript

This function takes in an array of key-value pair objects and returns a dictionary of the keys to their values.

For example an input of

```
[{ key: 'prop1', value: 'value1' }, { key: 'prop2', value: 'value2' }]
```

would result in

```
{ prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2' };
```

If the user provides duplicate keys then throw an error with the message `'You cannot provide duplicate keys'`

```
function createDictionary(input) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
function createDictionary(input) {
  var res = {};

  input.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (!res.hasOwnProperty(obj.key)) {
      res[obj.key] = obj.value;
    } else {
      throw new Error('You cannot provide duplicate keys.');
    }
   });

   return res;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[{key:'prop1',value:'value1'},{key:'prop2',value:'value2'}]
var dict={}
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if (!(a[i]['key'] in dict)){
                dict[a[i]['key']]=a[i]['value']
        }
        else{
                throw new Error("Key already exists.")
        }
}
console.log(dict)
```

Try this logic. You could also use a foreach loop.